# Получение ELF заголовка

Tags: python, elf

Есть несколько бинарников скомпилированных под разные архитектуры, заведомо не известно под какую
Нужно средствами python (и только python) реализовать своего рода аналог утилиты 'file' в linux

Выполняя
/usr/bin/file example.arm

Получим выхлоп:
"ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (ARM), statically linked, stripped"

На python'е же достаточно будет получить архитектуру
Буду очень признателен за любую помощь в данном вопросе

Comment: Простите за глупый вопрос, а просто запускать утилиту file из питона не вариант?)

Comment: В этом и соль, что запустить file нету возможности, всё средствами питона и только :)

Comment: В википедии есть описание заголовка: 
[Executable and Linkable Format: Заголовок файла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#Заголовок_файла). Этого достаточно, чтобы получить нужную информацию о файле.